# Android - CouchBase lite - com.couchbase.lite.View - database.getExistingView

Tags: android, couchbase, couchbase-lite, couchbase-view

I'm working with an android application using couchbase lite.
I have a view `byDate` (with Mapper) which is created at the first launch of my application.
But when I close and re-launch my application. `database.getExistingView("byDate")` return an empty View. Is this normal or I'm missing something? Is this possible to save the view permanently in local? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal.  The view contains native code that cannot be serialized so it needs to be re-registered on each launch.